# Cargar Formulario hecho en QTDesigner - Python

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2

Estoy empezando a programar en Python, y como practica tome el ejemplo que subió en su canal de YouTube **"Straight Coding"**, donde creaba una aplicación para libros.
En la misma instalo un entorno virtual y configuro PySide2.
Seguí los pasos al pie de la letra, y no me figuró ningún errór, pero al momento de querer ejecutar la ventana, aunque le haga bien simple, me tira un error, que no posee el método show. Adjunto las imágenes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La estructura esta dividida de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código creado en el QtDesigner es el siguiente, convertido a Python:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el código que lanza la aplicación es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojala puedan ayudarme, llevo varias semanas buscando solución y probando diferente opciónes.

Comment: ¿No será `window.show()`? (con paréntesis). Sin paréntesis, `show` es un atributo; con paréntesis, es una llamada a función.

Comment: No, no es eso porque esta entre paréntesis. Solo que al sacar las capturas de pantalla borre sin querer, pero sigue tirando el mismo error.